# How to get response headers from WebBrowser control in .NET?

Tags: .net, browser, header

After WebBrowser.Navigate() how to retreive response headers returned by server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a [temporary pluggable namespace handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916(VS.85).aspx) for the http protocol to record the conversations with the server so you can look up them when you need to. See http://google-gears.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gears/localserver/ie/http_handler_ie.cc and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx for examples.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I need a small, pure .NET solution.

Comment: Hi Xaqron, How you solved this issue as i am already facing the same issue

Comment: If you have sample code for temporary pluggable namespace handler in c# please share as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible.  A web page is made up of many HTTP requests and responses.  You'd have to download the HTML yourself with HttpWebRequest.  Its Headers property gives you access to the response headers.

Comment: I mean for a specific request with known URL, not for the whole page which may fetch other resources and make new requests as you mentioned.

Comment: @Xaqron: HttpWebRequest won't interpret the HTML (if any) and do numerous requests. It will only do the HTTP request against that one known URL.

Comment: using "WebClient" it's already possible via "WebResponse.Headers". Also you can do it manually by proxies like Fiddler. Request a URL and read the headers from response. Each request has a unique response. For example opening www.google.com will produce 3 request:
1) http://www.google.com/
2) http://clients1.google.com/generate_204
3) http://www.google.com/csi?v=3&s=webhp&action=&e=17259...
The two latter are referred from first and are not of our interest